# Pass object of an @Input to MatTableDataSource Angular Material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

how to pass the object I receive in the `@Input() data` (Child Component) to the `dataSource`, the way I do it does not allow it to be received.
I leave an example of what I am doing in [this link:](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bvb7cx)

```
  @Input() data:PeriodicElement[];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(this.data);

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

    // console.log(this.dataSource)
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define the dataSource  and initialize it in ngOnInit method

```
@Input() data:PeriodicElement[];
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>();

 @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(this.data);
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

  // console.log(this.dataSource)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The best way would be to use the set property with input, like:

`@Input() set data(value) {}`

See the working example on [stackbitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-angular-material-table-data)

Comment: brilliant. going to do this to all of my tables with data from an input. thanks